# pull addContentHTML content from XML or HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created a js dialog window, which shows some HTML (below). My problem is, instead of simply hard-coding the shown content as a html string, I want to keep the text content in a separate XML or HTML, which is then pulled into the dialog by addContentHTML. How is that done?

Best regards

```
createDialog: function () {
    this.dialog = new Dialog({
        title: 'Version info', 
        id:'version_window', 
        resizable: true,
        width: 420
    });
    this.dialog.addContentHTML('<b>Latest public version: </b>1.0</br></br><b>Currently testing:</b> 1.01</br></br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the content from any hidden element in the DOM:

```
<div id="content" style="display: none">
    ...
</div>

this.dialog.addContentHTML(document.getElementById('content').innerHtml);
```

There is more than on the way to do this, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Hmm, it still causes me trouble. Here´s the full js:

Comment: if(typeof SpatialMap=='undefined') {
    window.SpatialMap = {};
}

SpatialMap.About = {

 dialog: null,
 page: 'about',
 
 show: function () {
  if (this.dialog === null) {
   this.createDialog ();
  }
  this.dialog.showDialog ();
 },
 
 hide: function () {
  if (this.dialog != null) {
   this.dialog.hideDialog ();
  }
 },

 createDialog: function () {
  
        this.dialog = new Dialog({
   title: 'Version info', 
   id:'version.xml',
   resizable: true,
   width: 420
  });
  
        this.dialog.addContentHTML(document.getElementByID('version.xml').innerHtml);
  
 }
 
};

Comment: I want to pull from the version.xml file. Wonder what im doing wrong?       Best regards